# FaspManager embedded client stops prematurely while sending multiple files

Tags: file, transfer

I am using FaspManager as an embedded client in my Java application. My program works fine when I am sending just a single file. When I am trying to send multiple files (each having its own session & jobId) they are starting well and progressing for some time. However, after several minutes when one or two of the transfers complete, rest all of the transfers are stopping without completing.

In the aspera log I can see below messages:

```
2019-02-11 20:48:22.985 INFO 11120 --- [il.SelectThread] c.c.e.t.aspera.FaspTransferListener : Client session: 149aaa9b-d632-43e4-9653-fbbf768c69b5 | PROGRESS | Rate: 353.6 Kb/s | Target rate: 1.0 Gb/s
2019-02-11 20:48:23.024 INFO 11120 --- [il.SelectThread] com.asperasoft.faspmanager.Session : 149aaa9b-d632-43e4-9653-fbbf768c69b5 - cancel sent
```

I have not been able to find out who/how a cancel request has been sent. I have tried searching in Google for possible cause but have not been able to resolve it yet. So, I will really appreciate any help on this.

Thank you,
Sourav

Answer (score 0):

The `cancel sent` message in `Session` is called if the user specifically calls `FaspManager#cancelTransfer(String sessionId)`, or `FaspManager#stop()`, or if an error occurs while reading an input stream in `FileTransferSession#addSource(StreamReader, String)`.

I'd guess you're calling stop on the FaspManager after the first session finishes, but I'd need a more complete log, or a snippet of your code to see.